# How to create function that either prints characters or moves cursor

Tags: vim, vi

I'm trying to learn vim/vimscript by making changes to my `.vimrc` as I find things I want to improve. One example is that I now print a paired closing paren whenever I type an open, using:

```
:inoremap ( ()<left>
```

This puts me back in the center of the parens, leaving me with a new problem.

**How can I write a function that, upon typing the `)` character in insert mode, moves a space to the right (without printing anything) if the cursor is currently over that same character, but prints it normally otherwise?**

I've tried the following, but it sounds like there's something I don't understand, since this will just print the literal string **'<Esc>la'** in the scenario where I want to move a space to the right.

```
:inoremap <expr> ) PrintParenIfNotOnParen()

:function PrintParenIfNotOnParen()
:  if getline(".")[col(".")-1] == ')'
:    return '<Esc>la'
:  else
:    return ')'
:  endif
:endfunction
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually in the help. By typing `:helpgrep Eatchar` you get:

> It is possible to move the cursor after an abbreviation:
>
> ```
>    :iab if if ()<Left>
> ```
>
> This does not work if 'cpoptions' includes the '<' flag. <>
>
> You can even do more complicated things.  For example, **to consume the
>   space typed after an abbreviation**:
>
> ```
>    func Eatchar(pat)
>       let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
>       return (c =~ a:pat) ? '' : c
>    endfunc
>    iabbr <silent> if if ()<Left><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>
> ```

In your case you need only to change the last line :

```
   function! Eatchar(pat)
      let l:c = nr2char(getchar(0))
      return (l:c =~ a:pat) ? '' : l:c
   endfunction
   iabbr <silent> ( ()<Left><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Return either `')'` or `'<right>'`. You don't anything more complex than that for now.

Abbreviations are not the way to proceed. Inoremapping are. A `<expr>` mapping should work fine.

Comment: This seems like my ideal solution, but when I try to return '<right>', it literally outputs the string '<right>' into my buffer.